# Fabricjs - Shift + Click not selecting more than one object on canvas

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

Running fabricjs 3

I'm playing around with fabricjs, which is great. However, I'm at a point where I can no longer Shift + Click to select multiple objects. I've tried calling canvas.renderAll(). I can still select a single object and move it around. I can programatically select multiple objects and group them, but at some point in my playing around the ability to Shift + Click stopped working.

Assuming that the state of my canvas and fabricjs needs to be updated or rendered somehow or reset something? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you able to create a fiddle/snippet stating the issue? As I can see, it [works](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/ed54nqks/).

Comment: https://codepen.io/zelfapp/pen/PvEdOe?editors=1010 Try to Shift + Click the silver stars or drag and select.

Comment: Oh, brother. const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById('c'), {
  selection: false
}) Notice the selection: false in the creation of canvas. I removed the selection:false and now it works.